# How to dynamically add a new input if other are filled Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input

I have three inputs:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="friend-email-input" placeholder="Email" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="friend-email-input" placeholder="Email" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="friend-email-input" placeholder="Email" />
```

How to add a new input if this three inputs adn previous are filled ?
I am using angular route and I would rather use Angular.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="field1" placeholder="Email" />  
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="field2" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="field3" placeholder="Email" />
    <input ng-show="field1.length && field2.length && field3.length" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="field4" placeholder="Email" />
</div>
```

Assign each input a model and then use ng-show to only display the 4th input if the length of the models are truthy (ie: nonzero).

Answer (score 0):

in your controller keep track of all the inputs that you need, starting from

```
$scope.inputs = [{value: ""}, {value: ""}, {value: ""}];
```

in your template you are going to iterate on this array to show the inputs yoou have

```
<div ng-app="main" ng-controller="MainController">
  <div ng-repeat="input in inputs track by $index">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Email" ng-model="input.value"/>
    <button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="addInput()">Add Input</button>
</div>
```

So when the remove button of an input is clicked that input gets removed if there are more than 3 inputs present

If the add input button is pressed we append an input text with a remove button

```
$scope.remove = function(index){
  if($scope.inputs.length > 3){
    $scope.inputs.splice(index, 1);  
  }
}

$scope.addInput = function(){
    $scope.inputs.push({value: ""})
}
```

here is an example [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgBZOv)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But how to add a new input if previous is dirty ? And how to firstly show 3 inputs and next generate new if ofher are filled ?

Comment: @user3313798 i updated the codepen example to include a button for removing each input and a button for adding inputs. a minimun of 3 inputs should be present